The string values that I entered are not being displayed
I am trying to create a C program that displays the most expensive and cheapest books (using a structure data type).
But when I input all the values, only the float values (book prices) show up, not the strings (titles and authors).
What steps can I take to fix this issue?
// Exercise N3 - Resource
// Structure.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    
    // Defining Structure.
    struct Book
    {
        char title[40];
        char author[40];
        float price;
    };
    
    struct Book book_1;
    struct Book book_2;
    struct Book book_3;
    
    // Variables Declarations.
    // Needed to deal with string values.
    
    char title_1[40];
    char title_2[40];
    char title_3[40];
    
    char author_1[40];
    char author_2[40];
    char author_3[40];
    
    
    printf("Hey User !\n");
    
    // First Book Information.
    printf("Enter first book's information\n");
    
    printf("Book's Title :\n");
    fgets(title_1,40,stdin);
    title_1[strlen(title_1) - 1] = '\0';
    strcpy(title_1,book_1.title);
    printf("%s",book_1.title);
    
    printf("Book's Author :\n");
    fgets(author_1,40,stdin);
    author_1[strlen(author_1) - 1] = '\0';
    strcpy(author_1,book_1.author);
    
    printf("Book's Price :\n");
    scanf("%f",&book_1.price);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    
    // Second Book Information.
    printf("Enter second book's information\n");
    
    printf("Book's Title :\n");
    fgets(title_2,40,stdin);
    title_2[strlen(title_2) - 1] = '\0';
    strcpy(title_2,book_2.title);
    
    printf("Book's Author :\n");
    fgets(author_2,40,stdin);
    author_2[strlen(author_2) - 1] = '\0';
    strcpy(author_2,book_2.author);
    
    printf("Book's Price :\n");
    scanf("%f",&book_2.price);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    
    // Third Book Information.
    printf("Enter third book's information\n");
    
    printf("Book's Title :\n");
    fgets(title_3,40,stdin);
    title_3[strlen(title_3) - 1] = '\0';
    strcpy(title_3,book_3.title);
    
    printf("Book's Author :\n");
    fgets(author_3,40,stdin);
    author_3[strlen(author_3) - 1] = '\0';
    strcpy(author_3,book_3.author);
    
    printf("Book's Price :\n");
    scanf("%f",&book_3.price);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    
    
    if (book_1.price > book_2.price && book_1.price > book_3.price)
    {
        printf("Title : %s\n",book_1.title);
        printf("Author : %s\n",book_1.author);
        printf("Price : %0.2f €\n",book_1.price);
    }
    else if (book_2.price > book_1.price && book_2.price > book_3.price)
    {
        printf("Title : %s\n",book_2.title);
        printf("Author : %s\n",book_2.author);
        printf("Price : %0.2f €\n",book_2.price);
    }
    else if (book_3.price > book_1.price && book_3.price > book_2.price)
    {
        printf("Title : %s\n",book_3.title);
        printf("Author : %s\n",book_3.author);
        printf("Price : %0.2f €\n",book_3.price);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    
    if (book_1.price < book_2.price && book_1.price < book_3.price)
    {
        printf("Title : %s\n",book_1.title);
        printf("Author : %s\n",book_1.author);
        printf("Price : %0.2f €\n",book_1.price);
    }
    else if (book_2.price < book_1.price && book_2.price < book_3.price)
    {
        printf("Title : %s\n",book_2.title);
        printf("Author : %s\n",book_2.author);
        printf("Price : %0.2f €\n",book_2.price);
    }
    else if (book_3.price < book_1.price && book_3.price < book_2.price)
    {
        printf("Title : %s\n",book_3.title);
        printf("Author : %s\n",book_3.author);
        printf("Price : %0.2f €\n",book_3.price);
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}


I tried to change character array's size but I can't solve the problem.

Swap the arguments of strcpy(), it's first argument is destination and second is source. JFYI, fflush(stdin) is undefined behavior.


title_1[strlen(title_1) - 1] = '\0'; - do you mean to cut the last character off or have you misunderstood 0 termination ?2.strcpy(author_1,book_1.author); strcpy's first arg is where to copy to, the second is where to copy from.


I think it's time for you to learn about arrays and loops and how to use them. :)

Your basic error is simple, and was identified in comments. You have the argument to strcpy in the wrong order. The destination goes first, followed by the source.
However, there is no need to ever use strcpy at all. You can read straight into each book's char arrays.
You can also use an array of books rather than three separate variables. You then need only define a comparator and you can sort your array, giving you the most expensive and least expensive books. Surely this is superior to copying and pasting your code, especially if you wish to grow beyond a sample size of three books.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 40
#define NUM_BOOKS 3

struct Book {
    char title[STR_LEN];
    char author[STR_LEN];
    float price;
};

int compare_books_by_price(const void *a, const void *b) {
    struct Book *c = (struct Book *)a;
    struct Book *d = (struct Book *)b;

    if (c->price == d->price) return 0;
    if (c->price < d->price) return -1;
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    struct Book books[NUM_BOOKS];

    printf("Hey User !\n");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_BOOKS; i++) {
        printf("Enter #%zu book's information\n", i+1);

        printf("Book's Title :\n");
        fgets(books[i].title, STR_LEN, stdin);
        books[i].title[strlen(books[i].title) - 1] = '\0';
    
        printf("Book's Author :\n");
        fgets(books[i].author, STR_LEN, stdin);
        books[i].author[strlen(books[i].author) - 1] = '\0';
    
        printf("Book's Price :\n");
        scanf("%f", &books[i].price);
        fflush(stdin);
    } 

    qsort(books, NUM_BOOKS, sizeof(struct Book), compare_books_by_price);

    // books[0] is now the least expensive
    // books[NUM_BOOKS - 1] is now the most expensive
}

You should also be checking that your input succeeded and handling cases where it didn't appropriately.

Better, but... Still promotes use of non-portable "technique" (ie: fflush(stdin);)... Recommend using fgets() for 3rd field into temp buffer, then strtod(). (scanf() is a mess to get right.)... And, casting const void * pointers to struct Book * is unnecessary (excess verbiage that are just more maintenance points...) (Casting away const is not healthy...)
